# How to get PayPal TransactionID via eBay API

Tags: asp.net, paypal, ebay-api

I need to get PayPal TransactionID of the paid order on eBay via API.

I use ExternalTransaction like described here: https://ebay.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1550/~/linking-ebay-and-paypal-transactions

```
    ExternalTransactionType[] externalTransactionTypeArr = transactionType.ExternalTransaction;
```

but eBay API always returns null as transactionType.ExternalTransaction

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the DetailLevel to RETURN_ALL?

Comment: This is right answer to my question! Thanks!

Comment: How can I mark question as answered?

Comment: @McIntosh: Please post your comment as an answer so ihorko can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the Attribute "DetailLevel" to the value "RETURN_ALL".